# Creating a UITextField that creates a new line when needed

Tags: ios, text, uitextfield

I was wondering how I could create a UITextField that would create a new line when the text reaches it's edge.

Here how I am creating the text view:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 194, 320, 568);
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIView *textPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, 20)];
textField.leftView = textPaddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't do that. `UITextField` is only designed to have one line of text. The control that you should be using is `UITextView`, which supports the behavior you've described natively.

Comment: With a UITextView, can the user write the text @jafar

Comment: @matthew The user can enter any text into a text view.